# Azure AD B2C Sign in with Apple Throws a Generic Error AADB2C90289 on Redirect

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, sign-in-with-apple

I cannot get sign into Apple to work with any user flow in Azure B2C. I am using the base interface on B2C and attempting to run a user flow. When I select Sign in with Apple in the flow it redirects to Apple and handles the sign in but when I hit continue it throws AADB2C90289 and fails.

So far I've gone through the set up for Apple sign in with Azure probably five times now. I've configured the app group, app service, signed the JWT key from Apple. I can test everything, run my secret through jwt.ms and it all looks fine.

I'm using https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration as the metadata endpoint which seems fine. I tested the metadata with an Azure function and it was ultimately the same result. If I turn off the Azure function then I can see a relevant error. So I know that is not the issue.

I've followed this guide so many times that I can do the whole process without thinking about it.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple

Microsoft support has been unable to assist as the most they've done to help was to show me logs with no real information and ask if I'd used the link above.

Comment: Check the closed issues on the repo there. 99% of the time it’s a bad secret. There is nothing else to go wrong.

Comment: This is my current Apple secret.
 {
  "alg": "ES256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}.{
  "sub": "com.companyname.b2cservice",
  "nbf": 1598995077,
  "exp": 1614550677,
  "iss": "teamid",
  "aud": "https://appleid.apple.com"
}.[Signature]

I have checked the closed issues. I have changed the secret multiple times, created a new key and signed the key with the correct information multiple times and no change.

Comment: Found the solution and advised Microsoft support on how to update their documentation. You need to sign the key with values not offered in the github.com/azure documentation. To resolve the issue you will need to follow this page on how to sign the key properly. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/04/what-the-heck-is-sign-in-with-apple